# Firebase rules simulator: how to simulate push

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

Here's my database:

```
{
  "lists": {
    "list1_id_1": {
      "field1": "some value",
      "field2": "some value"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to allow any user to create new lists, but not modify existing ones, so I tried the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lists": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

This didn't work when I tried to write the following data to `/lists/`:

```
{ "field1": "qq", "field2": "ww" }
```

Apparently, the ".write" rule failed the write because /lists/ already exists.

So I tried the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lists": {
      ".read": "true",
      "$list_id": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This didn't work either, Firebase simulator didn't select the rule which failed the write operation, so I guess it's because the ".write" is missing from "lists".

Could you please help me out here?
I think my problem is with both the rules, and the way I tried to push a new item to /lists/ in the simulator.

P.S.  I know the list_id will be generated by Firebase when I try to push new data, but I'm not sure how to use this knowledge for the simulator.

Thanks!
Slavik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second set of rules should do the job, but you'll need to specify a child ID in the simulator:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lists": {
      ".read": "true",
      "$list_id": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$list_id` variable points to any child under the `/lists` node, so within the simulator, you'll need to set the location to `/lists/list1_id_1` to test writing to a child that already exists, which should fail, something like:

[image: simulator screenshot]

A `push` operation creates a child with a unique ID at the given location. To simulate this, you just need to set the location to any random child key that you know doesn't already exist, for example: `/lists/some-random-string` or `/lists/-Kfg3YL0TS1X1SfQ9GGg`.

Comment: But how do I simulate pushing a new item to /lists/ in the simulator to make sure the rule is correct?

Comment: A `push` is just creating a child with a unique ID at the given location. So, in the simulator, you just need to set the location to any child key that you know doesn't already exist: `/lists/some-random-string`. The simulator doesn't have a built-in push simulation, but doing this is effectively the same thing. I've updated my answer with this.